# How to use Formdata upload a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to upload file cross domain. I think the bug is in js part.

But I can't figure it out what exactly wrong.

```
<form id="upload">
      <div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
              <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Submit()" type="button">submit</button>
          </div>
      </div>
</form>
```

Here is my js

```
var form = $('#upload');
var formData = new FormData(form);

$.ajax({
    url: URLs,
    data: formData,
    cache:false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'jsonp',

    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg["foo"]);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> dataType:'jsonp',
> ```

JSONP is incompatible with POST requests (which file uploads require).

Use any other dataType supported by jQuery.

Since you are making a cross origin request, you will need the target server to grant you permission via CORS.

Comment: But I have to cross domain.What kink of dataType can cross domain? I only found jsonp

Comment: @user3927463 — Any kind. See the final paragraph of this answer.

Comment: Could you give me some links about CORS? This is my first time deal with this problem. I have no idea what keyword should I search.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cors is a good start. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing and http://enable-cors.org/ and in the top 4 hits and are all useful.

Comment: One more question, why can't I use jsonp while uploading file?

Comment: Because JSONP is incompatible with POST requests (which file uploads require).

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button, you're calling the function `Submit()` but it isn't defined in your js. This should work:

```
function Submit()
{
    var form = $('#upload');
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: URLs,
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'jsonp',

        success: function(msg){
            alert(msg["foo"]);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I forgot to post it. In my js, I have.

Comment: is the `URLs` var defined?